# UISegmentedControl in static UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am having a very strange problem with a `UISegmentedControl` that would not be expected with such a simple interface element. I have designed a static cell for my tableview in my Storyboard (the table view has 8 cells, many of them with interface elements like steppers and labels that work fine) that contains a `UISegmentedControl`. I linked the interface object to the following proper and method:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *plantHealthSegmentedControl;
- (IBAction)plantHealthValueChanged:(id)sender;
```

Strangely, when I initialize the segmented control in the `viewDidLoad` method, the interface object does not change from the default values set in the Storyboard editor. This is the code used to modify it in my implementation file for the table view:

```
plantHealthSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Excellent", @"Good", @"Poor", @"Dead", nil]];
plantHealthSegmentedControl.tintColor = gardenGreenColor;
plantHealthSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
```

My `plantHealthValueChanged` method is the following (**it always logs -1 as the selected index**)

```
- (IBAction)plantHealthValueChanged:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Segmented control index = %i", plantHealthSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex);
}
```

Any help with this strange issue is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are reinitializing your control. This wipes out the storyboard reference and makes a brand new one that isn't hooked up to anything.

You need to get rid of this line:

```
plantHealthSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Excellent", @"Good", @"Poor", @"Dead", nil]];
```

I recommend simply setting the segment info in interface builder directly since you create the control there.

Or if you want to do it in code there are a few ways. You can use `insertSegmentWithTitle:atIndex:animated:` to add them individually. If however, any segments are coming from the NIB, you would probably want to call `removeAllSegments` first.